# How to count unique days in excel after autofiltering

Tags: excel

I have a sheet where I would like to count the unique days. What I mean by that is, the data covers 1 Jan 2017 to 31 Dec 2017, but not all dates are included. When autofiltered, even less days are showing. I have tried many different formulas I have been given, but they all fall over when the sheet is autofiltered for the required criteria. The closest one was an array formula, entered in Excel for Mac 16.43. It was entered using Ctrl & Shift & Enter

```
=SUM(IFERROR(IF(FREQUENCY(A3:A5524,A3:A5524),IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A3:A5524,ROW(A3:A5524)-ROW(A3),0,1)),1)),0))
```

It counts the correct number of days when the sheet is unfiltered, the number changes as the sheet is autofiltered, but again becomes incorrect when this is done. There might be a date range showing of 6 Jan 2017 to 20 June 2017, but only have 75 actual days showing in that range; nothing I have yet tried can get it accurate after autofiltering

[image]

The data is laid out in a pretty standard way with column A being date and it is formatted as Date and dd/mm/yyyy

Hopefully someone can suggest something which works

Comment: What is your excel version? Post data to post body instead of image. Also show your expected result.

Comment: Upload the Excel file and keep only the columns that need to be calculated. I have solved similar problems before, and I hope I can help you.

Comment: cheers Harun24hr. Excel version was listed in the original post. Expected results are the correct count of how many unique days appear. An answer came to light though

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being the following

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A3:A5524,ROW(A3:A5524)-ROW(A3),0,1)),A3:A5524),A3:A5524),1))
```

Rather than the original formula

cheers

Answer (score 0):

*Array formula*

```
=COUNT(0/FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(A2,ROW(1:5522),)),MATCH(A3:A5524,A3:A5524,),),ROW(1:5555)))
```

Note parameter, if column A is a date, the use of 2, if column A is text, using a 3, but FREQUENCY unavailable.